Microsoft Graph how to retrieve recordings and transcripts?
I was able to successfully create notification subscriptions for recording creation and transcript creation using Microsoft.Identity.Web.GraphServiceClient. The notification contains resource property that looks something like this (shortened for brevity):
"resource": "communications/onlineMeetings('MSo5NzZmN ... XhAdGhyZWFkLnYy')/recordings('VjIjIzE5NzZmNG ... JlNzI=')"

and the docs say I can use this to download the recording (or transcript). But it seems this is a portion of a URL. Is there some way to use GraphServiceClient to do the download or do I need to make an HTTPS call using an HTTPClient? The only way I can see to download a recording or transcript with GraphServiceClient is if I have the MeetingId and RecordingId (or TranscriptId), which are not included in the notification.
Looking at the API docs for HTML calls, it appears the only way to retrieve a recording is if you have the organizer's Id which isn't returned in the notification. Can someone guide me how to retrieve the transcript or recording using what's returned in the notifications?
